# Android play store icon development software

Tags: icons

I'm trying to develop an icon for my app, specifically the play store icon which is 512 x 512. I've Google for days now and only find Photoshop stuff, which is too expensive for me and the learning curve just for one icon is not worth it.

Do any of you know of cheaper software that I can buy and use, specifically something that just help you create high quality icons?

I am also open to courses for Gimp and Paint that can teach you, but not Photoshop please.  I know they are the best but they don't think of guys like me that are starting out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the proper place for this kind of question, but I think Gimp seems the most reasonable option. The web is full of tutorials for it, so I think it's worth searching there. For example: [Creating Icons](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Creating_Icons/)